# Scrapy & Selenium

Tags: selenium, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a single page using Scrapy and Selenium

```
import time
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver

class SampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "sample"
    start_urls = ['url-to-scrape']

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        time.sleep(30)
        for page in response.css('a'):
            yield {
                'url-href': page.xpath('@href').extract(),
                'url-text': page.css('::text').extract()
            }
        self.driver.quit()
```

The spider doesn't capture know  tags and outputs:

```
{"url-text": [" "], "url-href": ["javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(\"ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl01$ctl00$ctl01\", \"\", true, \"\", \"\", false, true))"]},
{"url-text": [" "], "url-href": ["javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(\"ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl01$ctl00$ctl02\", \"\", true, \"\", \"\", false, true))"]},
{"url-text": [" "], "url-href": ["javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(\"ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl01$ctl00$ctl03\", \"\", true, \"\", \"\", false, true))"]}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading the response from scrapy and trying to work the code on the selenium page this won't work. You need to use the response from your selenium page and create a scrapy response object from the same.

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver

class SampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "sample"
    start_urls = ['url-to-scrape']

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        res = response.replace(body=self.driver.page_source)

        for page in res.css('a'):
            yield {
                'url-href': page.xpath('@href').extract(),
                'url-text': page.css('::text').extract()
            }
        self.driver.quit()
```

Also `time.sleep` is not needed in this case

Comment: wouldn't `self.driver.get(response.url)` have to be something like `self.driver.get(response.body)` instead?! doesn't `response.url` simply return the URL? i'm trying to figure out how to use scrapy and selenium side-by-side, but it is almost impossible to find info anywhere online regarding how to do this

Comment: @Anthony, `response.body` gives you plain HTML response, with JS not executed. That is why we use `response.url` and browser the same url in the selenium driver. Then we use `self.driver.page_source` to get the rendered HTML with javascript executed